# Gatekeeper dialog on El Capitan is missing... localized strings?

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

I really have no idea what to make of this, but on one of the machines I've upgraded to El Capitan, all of the gatekeeper dialogs display without localized strings:

[image: weird gatekeeper dialog]

This displays after launching Chromium from the dock just after having replaced it with a new version by copying an app bundle from a DMG to the Applications folder.

This is clearly not expected behavior, but I'm not sure what I could do to fix it besides reinstalling El Cap (which I'm not too keen on doing if I can avoid it).

Has anyone else seen anything like this, and/or have any ideas for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

I have no definite solution since I haven't seen this issue before, but a few ideas you could try:

- Running "First Aid" on your drive in Disk Utility
- If you have Time Machine enabled, revert to the latest viable backup
- Find out what exactly you replaced and undo (parts of) that manually